# Sass --watch doesn't find anything, not compiling

Tags: sass, watch

I'm trying to use SASS but I got some issue with it, is not compiling anything. I tried different things to troubleshoot, is still not working.
Ruby 2.0.0-p576
Sass 3.4.5
Wind 7

```
sass --watch sass/scss.css:css/style.css
```

OR

```
sass --watch scss.css:css.css
```

result:

> > sass is watching for change .press Ctr-C to stop.

```
 write sass/scss.css
 write sass/scss.css.map
```

config.rb

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
css_dir = 'css'
sass_dir = 'sass'
images_dir = './img'
javascript_dir = 'js'
output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

Thanks

Comment: ` write sass/scss.css write sass/scss.css.map` this makes me thinks it writes output css files in the "sass" folder...

Comment: can you post your config.rb and your project layout?

Comment: Is your sass file named `scss.css`? The `sass --watch` will be looking for files with the extension of .scss or .sass, not .css. If you rename your sass file to `style.scss`, it should compile to `style.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, there are a couple of things to fix.

First, you'll want your .scss files to have the same name as your compiled .css files, just with a different extension. In this case, you'd name your .scss file `style.scss`, and sass will save the compiled result to `style.css`.

The second thing I notice is that you're using compass, with a `config.rb` file. This suggests that you probably don't want to use the `sass --watch` command to start Sass, since going this route will not actually enable Compass to be used in your Sass files. The way to invoke compass here is to run `compass watch` from the directory that encloses your `/sass` and `/css` directories (since those are specified in your `config.rb` file.

Fixing those two items will probably get your Sass compiler running the way you want. Here's what the resulting structure should look like:

```
/enclosing_folder
  config.rb
  /css
    style.css (this will be added by the sass compiler)
  /sass
    style.scss
```

In this example, run `compass watch` from `enclosing_folder`.